# How to remove ftp user from blocked list using shell?

Tags: shell, ftp

under CentOS using VSFTPD server we can block a user from FTP access using shell command

```
echo tom >> /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
```

where tom is username.

Is it possible to UNBLOCK the same user tom by a shell command ?
Thanks for a hint !

Answer (score 1):

Use this to comment the line starting with tom:

```
     sed -i 's/^tom/#tom/' /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
```

Comment: Simple and brilliant ! but can I remove tom at all (as I'm sure that no any conflicts to damage other usernames like tomas or atomic where "tom" is?

Comment: If you want (sensibly) to require `tom` be a whole word, then you need a word boundary afterwards, like this... `sed 's/^tom[[:>:]]/#tom/' ftpusers`